# Service Work storage a JSON when recive a push and keep for future uses

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

Heres is my problem.

I am work around the payload push notification key verification "I cant implement in the server to generate those keys to send with CURL. If you know a way, please.. show me. "

When sent a push to gcm/send the SW in my site works fine, well, beside "data:null". then i do a request with the endtpoint to the server. Works fine when the page is on and the SW not updated .. when goes to offline i lost the object "endpoint" .. i can´t use localStorage or cookies in SW. I was think use caches. But there is another way to save data in SW side ?

Note: The SW still respond and work fine offline. The problem is the lost of object, seems a hibernate stage and when wake up is running from zero the "sw.js"

Thank you very much .. 
sorry the english

Answer (score 1):

I personally used [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/learn.html) for my project. It is very easy understand and get used-to. 
Usage is as simple as:

**Initialization:**

```
var newDB = new PouchDB('new_database', {
 auto_compaction: true
});
```

**Get/Put**

```
newDB.get('new_variable').then(function(doc) {
        //operations.
        return doc
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). Try [localForage](https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/) for a quick implementation of a key/value storage.